# Reassign positions to the latitudes and longitudes defined by a grid

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have some data for ozone levels at some UK monitoring sites, with the latitude and longitude of each site given e.g:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[33.      , 52.411563, -1.560228],
       [45.      , 52.437165, -1.829999],
       [31.      , 52.47609 , -1.875024],
       [53.      , 50.5976  , -3.71651 ],
       [39.      , 50.37167 , -4.142361],
       [41.      , 50.725083, -3.532465],
       [69.      , 51.05625 , -2.68345 ],
       [38.      , 51.462839, -2.584482],
       [56.      , 50.73957 , -1.826744]],columns = ['values','lat','lon'])
```

I would like to plot these points as gridsquares, coloured by their average value for points which lie within the same grid box, using an official grid-0.25x0.3125km, whose latitudes and longitudes are given by:

```
grid = {'lon':np.linspace(-15.00,40,177),
            'lat':np.linspace(32.75,61.25,115)} #should define the grid squares for the map
```

I have tried to go through my latitude and longitude columns, reassigning each value to its nearest lat-lon pair. This SEEMS to work.

```
for i, [time, val, lat, lon] in DEFRAO3.iterrows():
    pos_lat = bisect_left(nested_grid['lat'],lat)
    new_lat = nested_grid['lat'][pos_lat]
    pos_lon = bisect_left(nested_grid['lon'],lon)
    new_lon = nested_grid['lon'][pos_lat]

    DEFRAO3.set_value(i, 'latitude', new_lat)
    DEFRAO3.set_value(i, 'longitude', new_lon)
DEFRAO3
```

Gives:

[image: grid-adjusted measurement locations]

Then, averaging for positions with the same (lat,lon):

```
newDEFRA = DEFRAO3.groupby(['latitude','longitude'], as_index=False).mean()
```

But when I plot it, all my points are along the same diagonal line.

[image: All points are along the same diagonal line, which is not correct]

Answer (score 0):

The [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/) library contains some useful plotting functions for these kinds of plots.

The following code will produce the plot that I think you're looking for:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

df = ...

# you might want to round lat/lon as appropriate before grouping

df2 = df.groupby(["lat", "lon"]).mean()
df2 = df2.unstack()  # Turns your long dataframe into a 2D dataframe.
df2 = df2.sort_index(ascending=False)  # Highest latitude first

sns.heatmap(df2, cmap="viridis", cbar="right")
plt.show()
```